# Spring Security OAuth2 Setting Custom Error Page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, oauth, spring-security

I am currently implementing Spring Security OAuth2 and would like to provide my own custom error page when an `OAuth2Exception` is thrown.  Currently there is a Framework endpoint in WhitelabelErrorEndpoint.java that is mapped to `/oauth/error`, which provides the default error handling.  The reference docs claim:

> All you need to do is provide a Spring MVC controller with @RequestMappings for those endpoints, and the framework defaults will take a lower priority in the dispatcher.

However, in practice I am not seeing my Spring controller taking priority over the Whitelabel default.  What am I doing wrong?

Example Controller:

```
@Controller
@Scope(WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST)
public class OAuthExceptionController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OAuthExceptionController.class);

    @RequestMapping("/oauth/error")
    public ModelAndView defaultOAuthErrorHandler(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        logger.error("Oauth2 exception occurred");
        Map<String, Object> model = Maps.newLinkedHashMap();
        model.put("path", request.getServletPath());
        return new ModelAndView("error/accessDenied", model);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried the 'ControllerAdvice' annotation? see here for more details: https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Comment: @ManuZi - I did try 'ControllerAdvice' however that ended up not being what I was looking for as the provided AuthorizationEndpoint is already handling exceptions. The handler routes directly to the /oauth/error endpoint with a ModelAndView.